# Is it possible to change to C# or C+ in visual express / vb

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Im currently building a windows application and I was wondering, since i have more experience with C# how can i turn my vb application into a C#. Do i have to restart everything back over with a C# application or what?

Comment: Maybe.  Maybe not.  You cannot possibly expect an accurate answer on a question like this, nobody knows what your project looks like and how far it got along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most C# and VB code can be converted from one to the other mechanically, though there are a few edge-case exceptions.

There are a number of tools out there [including this one](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cc8da841-f978-4c3e-8397-c820bd57298c) that can significantly help with the conversion.

Alternatively, if you have some aspects of your project that are fairly complete, you can use the VB project (e.g. a library) from another C# project.

Answer (score 0):

For VB to C# and vice versa, these are both .NET languages, there are some pretty good converters of these - just google a bit; the only complication can be in arrays, which aren't really easy to recognize in VB. For C++ to these languages and vice versa, I am afraid that it won't be that easy, as both languages are of different basics.